# Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a\**\drop.zip<br/>

Tags: azure-devops, pipeline

I've tried to do a pipeline with Python, but I got these errors. Anyone can help me? I am trying to do a Pipeline (CI/CD) for a web app in Python, which needs the: -Web App Server,-Database,-SonarQube. I created the database separately and put the connection information in my code, but I know it's not the best way to do it. I really appreciate any help you can provide. Follow you can see my Pipeline.yaml and the error that I got.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRtWr.png)

Here you can see my pipeline:

```
# # Python to Linux Web App on Azure
# Build your Python project and deploy it to Azure as a Linux Web App.
# Change the python version to one that is appropriate for your application.
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/python

trigger:
- master

variables:
  # Azure Resource Manager connection created during pipeline creation
  azureServiceConnectionId: '*****************************'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: ubuntu-latest

  # Environment name
  environmentName: StudentWebappDev

  # Project root folder. Point to the folder containing manage.py file.
  projectRoot: C:\codes\StudentWebApp

  # Python version: 3.7
  pythonVersion: 3.7

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: BuildJob
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '$(pythonVersion)'
      displayName: 'Use Python $(pythonVersion)'

    - script: |
        python -m venv antenv
        source antenv/bin/activate
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install setup
        pip freeze > requirements.txt
        pip install -r requirements.txt
      workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
      displayName: "Install requirements"

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

#    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
#      displayName: 'Upload package'
#      artifact: drop

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        artifactName: drop
        publishLocation: 'Container'

    - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
      inputs:
        artifactName: drop
        downloadPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'

    - task: AzureWebApp@1
      inputs:
        package: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip  
        azureSubscription: 65e5170f-cbf2-4dc7-99a8-533049eea21d
        appName: AppServiceStudentWeb
      
- stage: Deploy
  displayName: 'Deploy Web App'
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeploymentJob
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    environment: StudentWebappDev
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: UsePythonVersion@0
            inputs:
              versionSpec: '$(pythonVersion)'
            displayName: 'Use Python version'`
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied your yaml, confirm **Build** stage part is working. Task `AzureWebApp@1` is version 1.x(suggest to add `appType` as it's required).

Check your error screenshot, suppose the `Azure App service deploy` task(version **4.229.0**) should exist in your **Deploy** stage, but i cannot find it in your yaml.

Different stages will execute on different agents(machines). If `drop.zip` is created in Build stage, to use it in `Deploy` stage, you need to download the artifact on Deploy stage. Please notice the download path used.

You can check the [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#example) for your reference.

If you still have queries, please show the completed yaml.

Comment: Hi @Stormshadow007, may i know if there's any update?